# Calculating using SUM, query does not work?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.

**a)** ai_account

[image]

**b)** ai_order_product

[image]

i want to do some calculations for particular supplier_id.

> 1, totalAmount, i want to do something like
>   SUM(ai_order_product.quantity * ai_order_product.cost)
>
> 2, amountPaid, this is total amount paid by the supplier that will be
>   something like SUM(ai_account.amount) with reference to supplier_id.
>
> 3) balance, this will be calculated by SUM(ai_order_product.quantity *
>   ai_order_product.cost) - SUM(ai_invoice.amount)
>
> 4) lastPayment date, that will be MAX(ai_account.addDate).

i tried doing something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) as totalAmount, 
       SUM(ac.amount) as amountPaid, 
       SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) - SUM(ac.amount) as balance, 
       MAX(ac.addDate) as lastPayment 
    FROM ai_order_product op 
        LEFT JOIN ai_account ac 
            ON (op.supplier_id = ac.trader_id) 
    WHERE op.supplier_id = 42
```

it does not work properly, it fetches some unexpected values, whereas the result for the above being expected is,

```
for supplier_id = 42,
1) totalAmount = 1375,
2) amountPaid = 7000,
3) balance = -5625,
4) lastPayment = 2011-11-23

and for supplier_id = 35,
1) totalAmount = 1500,
2) amountPaid = 43221,
3) balance = -41721,
4) lastPayment = 2011-11-28

and for supplier_id = 41
1) totalAmount = 0
2) amountPaid = 3000,
3) balance = -3000,
4) lastPayment = 2011-11-09
```

i want to fetch one row by supplier_id.

P.S:  i just entered some dummy values that is why the calculations are mostly negative whereas in application the calculated values will be positive.

Comment: There's no `trader_id` in either of your tables...

Comment: that was by mistake, i changed it to supplier_id :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because each "ai_order_product" row is getting counted multiple times (once for each row present in the ai_account table).

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  op.totalAmount as totalAmount
  , SUM(ac.amount) as amountPaid
  , op.totalAmount - SUM(ac.amount) as balance
  , MAX(ac.addDate) as lastPayment 
FROM (
  select supplier_id, sum(quantity * cost) as totalAmount 
  from ai_order_product
  group by supplier_id) op 
LEFT JOIN ai_account ac ON (op.supplier_id = ac.trader_id) 
WHERE op.supplier_id = 42
```

This may be slightly off, but this general logic should work.

Comment: this throws following error.`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'op.quantity' in 'field list'`

Comment: this works fine, however i have a situation here, i think ill post it as new question. thank you @Darek. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use to state **GROUP BY**, when using aggregate functions like **SUM** in **SELECT** statements.

```
SELECT op.supplier_id as supplierId,
       SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) as totalAmount, 
       SUM(ac.amount) as amountPaid, 
       SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) - SUM(ac.amount) as balance, 
       MAX(ac.addDate) as lastPayment 
    FROM ai_order_product op 
        LEFT JOIN ai_account ac 
            ON (op.supplier_id = ac.trader_id)
    GROUP BY op.supplier_id
    HAVING supplierId = 42
```

Comment: this does not work, it fetches the multiplied result for example for id 42 it fetches for totalAmount = 2750 wheras it should be 1375 and for amount paid it fetched 14000 wheras i am expecting 7000.

Comment: @Andreas: group by is only required if you've got non-aggregated fields in the query.

Comment: @MarcB, do you have any solution to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
  SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) as totalAmount 
  , ac2.amountPaid 
  , SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) - ac2.balance 
  , ac2.lastPayment  
FROM ai_order_product op  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
             ac.supplier_id
             , MAX(ac.addDate) as lastPayment
             , SUM(ac.amount) as balance 
           FROM ai_account ac 
           WHERE (op.supplier_id = ac.supplier_id)
           GROUP BY ac.supplier_id) ac2 ON (ac2.supplier_id = op.supplier_id)  
WHERE op.supplier_id = 42 
GROUP BY op.supplier_id
```

The `group by` clauses kick in when you're selecting more than one supplier_id.

Comment: i am weak at mysql, and not able to figure it out, this query simply does not work. it gives out following error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ac2 ON (ac2.trader_id = op.supplier_id)  
WHERE op.supplier_id = 42 
GROUP BY op' at line 13`

Comment: Fixed the query ac.trader_id -> supplier_id

Comment: the actual field was ac.trader_id, i had changed it to supplier_id to avoid confusion, even after making changes it does not work for me :(

Comment: after correcting the fields it gives me this error. Unknown column 'op.supplier_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your expected and actual values are doubled. After entering your sample data and running the query, I get (for supplier_id = 42)

```
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
| totalAmount | amountPaid | balance | lastPayment |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
|        2750 |      14000 |  -11250 | 2011-11-23  |
+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

That's because you've got 2 rows in each table that match the join criteria, causing a doubling of the results.

Comment: yeah, that is what is happening, i am not expecting that result. what should i be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first get the sub totals for one of the tables so that you only have 1 row coming back. thus the inner select here returns the max and the sum, so when you join to it you only get 1 row.

```
SELECT SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) as totalAmount, 
       ac.addDate as lastPayment, 
       ac.amount as amountPaid, 
       SUM(op.quantity * op.cost) - SUM(ac.amount) as balance
    FROM ai_order_product op 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT max(IaiaddDate) as addDate, sum(iai.amount) as Amount, iai.supplier_ID 
            FROM ai_account iai 
            Group by supplier_ID) ac 
        ON AC.Supplier_ID = Op.Supplier_ID
    WHERE op.supplier_id = 42
```

Group by Ac.addDate, ac.amount, op.supplier_ID --Just incase where clause is left off.